# Twig Custom Extension - call parent() in extending block

Tags: symfony, twig, extend

is there any way to call [parent()](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/parent.html) function in extending block in the template of the custom extension?

In my base.html.twig I have block `footer_javascript` and in my custom extension I would like to add some JS to this block but I need to ensure that original block `footer_javascript` will be extended not overwritten. I tried this:

custom_extension.html.twig:

```
{# some html/twig code, not really important #}
{% block footer_javascript %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {# some javascript for this custom twig extension #}
{% endblock footer_javascript %}
```

but of course, I get

> Calling "parent" on a template that does not extend nor "use" another
>   template is forbidden

base.html.twig - base template with block structure:

```
{# base html/twig structure, not really important %}

{# block which will be extended/overwriten in templates which extends this base.html.twig #}
{% block footer_javascript %}
{% endblock footer_javascript %}
```

extended.html.twig - template which extends base.html.twig; in this template I am using custom twig extension:

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{# some html/twig ... #}

{{ custom_extension(entity) }}

{% block footer_javascript %}
{{ parent() }}
{# javascript used for extend.html.twig #}
{% endblock footer_javascript %}
```

Is there any way to extend base `footer_javascript` in my custom extension template?

Comment: Can you show your template as well as your `base.html.twig`?

Comment: @bartek I added some outline for base.html.twig, but the other code is not really important. If you have some specific question just ask and I'll try to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `parent()`, you have to extend the template.

Your `custom_extension.html.twig` has to extend `base.html.twig` like `extended.html.twig`.

**EDIT:**
If you're using 2 templates with `<body>`, you don't have to use `{{ parent() }}`, but instead put your js in a twig that you will include in your block.

Comment: I tried this and I replied to bartek but he deleted his answer. When I am extending custom_extension.html.twig I get this error: "A template that extends another one cannot have a body in custom_extension.html.twig"

Comment: Ok so if you're using 2 templates with <body>, you haven't to use {{ parent() }}, but instead put your js in a twig that you will include in your block.